# Obtener datos de tabla pivot con Eloquent - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Me encuentro con este problema que no puedo resolver:
Tengo una entidad llamada carrera, que contiene series:

```
class Carrera extends Model
{
    public function series(){
        return $this->hasMany(Serie::class, 'id_carrera');
    }
}
```

A su vez, la serie contiene a sus participantes, en una relación N a N, donde en la tabla intermedia, guardo datos de ese patinador en esa serie.

```
class Serie extends Model
{ 
   public function participantes(){
       return $this->belongsToMany(Patinador::class, 'serie_patinadores', 'id_serie', 'id_patin');
}
}
```

En la entidad Patinador, realizo la relación inversa.

Mi problema ocurre en el controlador de Carrera donde quiero obtener las series, con sus participantes y resultados.
Hice esto:

```
   public function verSeries($id_evento){
        $matchThese = ['id_event' => $id_evento];
        return Carrera::with('series', 'series.participantes')->where($matchThese)->get();
    }
```

Estructura de las tablas:

Carrera
id
nombre

Serie
id_serie
id_carrera

Serie_Patinador
id_serie
id_patin
puntos
descalificado

Patinador
id_patin
nombre

Me esta retornando las series con sus participantes, pero no la información de la tabla intermedia
(serie_patinadores), como puedo acceder a esa información?

Comment: Agrega la estructura de tus tablas por favor, además indícanos que es lo que quieres retornar de dicha tabla

Comment: Listo :)) @BetaM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cómo puedes comprobar en la propia [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns), notarás que:

- Para el modelo *pivot* solo estarán presentes las llaves de los modelos
- Cómo tú tabla pivot tiene dos columnas extra entonces debes declararlas al momento que defines la relación así

  ```
  public function participantes()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Patinador::class, 'serie_patinadores', 'id_serie', 'id_patin')
        ->withPivot('puntos', 'descalificado');
  }
  ```